# Alto sax screw fell out

Tags: maintenance, saxophone, repair, woodwinds

I have a Jupiter alto saxophone, and in the middle of practicing I suddenly heard something fall into the bell.  It turned out to be a small screw.  I scoured the sax trying to find an empty hole but was unsuccessful.  I'm still a beginner and don't know all of the keys, so it's also been hard for me to test where the screw might have come from.  I was hoping someone might have some suggestions for me to figure out where it goes.

It's got a circular head with a flathead line in it.  The diameter of the head is about 6mm, and the length of the screw is around 7mm.  After doing a little research, I'm guessing it may be a flower bar screw?

Thank you so much, any suggestions or resources would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: can you post a photo of the screw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it came from what I think is the high F key (I've never actually used it before)?  I went back to where I was practicing and found a small rod-like piece on the floor that I hadn’t noticed before.  So, it looks like the screw actually came loose from a rod that connects the high F button to a lever above it.  Got it all fixed now!

Comment: That's good that you found the matching part.  In general, if something falls off, stop playing immediately until you find where it came from.  Otherwise you risk bending or warping a rod that has lost its end support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the screws around that size are usually key guard screws. It may also be a lyre holder screw if your model has one.  Look on your key guards for a matching screw head and then look for open holes.

https://www.votawtool.com/key-guard-screw-large.html